# creating and dropping dynamically db_link each time connecting various DBs after updating table

Tags: plsql

I want to create PL-SQL procedure which connect and update various DBs remotely from one db and update table on each DBs by creating dynamic db_link and this db_link should be created and dropped each time after updating the tables in all DBs. How can we do it? Please help.

Comment: Why create and drop each time after updating tables?

Comment: Thanks Alvalongo for your reply. Actually my table's data are coming from MView and each time it has to be refreshed and reload the table with new records and i do not want to keep 100 db_links if i want to update 100 distributed DB table. So each time when the update  gets completed it should drop the db_links.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**: There is a security breach about creating and dropping dynamically  db links because a table must store passwords for every remote account.

1-Create a table

```
Table name: REMOTE_INFO

host_name        varchar2(25) primary_key,
username_remote  varchar2(30),
password_remote  varchar2(30),
host_connection  varchar2(30),
table_local      varchar2(30),
schema_remote    varchar2(30),
table_remote     varchar2(30),
condition        varchar2(4000)
```

2-Package specification

```
create or replace package pk_remote
is
  /* ====================================================================================================
  -- ref: question on
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339278/creating-and-dropping-dynamically-db-link-each-time-connecting-various-dbs-after
  -- 2019-05-30 by alvalongo
  ==================================================================================================== */
  kLINE_FEED   constant varchar2(1):=chr(10);
  --
  procedure pr_copy(p_iHost        varchar2,
                    p_oError   out number,
                    p_oMessage out varchar2
                   );
End pk_remote;
```

3-Package body

```
create or replace package body pk_remote
is
  /* ====================================================================================================
  -- ref: question on
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339278/creating-and-dropping-dynamically-db-link-each-time-connecting-various-dbs-after
  -- 2019-05-30 by alvalongo
  ==================================================================================================== */
  --
  procedure pr_copy(p_iHost        varchar2,
                    p_oError   out number,
                    p_oMessage out varchar2
                   )
  is
    rcRemote   remote_info%rowtype;
    vLink_name varchar2(30);
    vSentence  varchar2(2000);
    ex_exit    exception;
  Begin
    p_oError:=0;
    p_oMessage:=null;
    if p_iHost is null then
       p_oError:=100;
       p_oMessage:='HOST cannot be null';
       raise ex_exit;
    End if;
    Begin
      select a.*
      into rcRemote
      from remote_info a
      where a.host_name=upper(trim(p_iHost));
    Exception
      when no_data_found then
           p_oError:=sqlcode;
           p_oMessage:='There is no host='||upper(trim(p_iHost));
           raise ex_exit;
    end;
    --
    vLink_name:=upper('DBL_'||rcRemote.host_name);
    --
    vSentence:=  'CREATE DATABASE LINK '||vLink_name||kLINE_FEED
               ||'CONNECT TO '||rcRemote.username_remote||kLINE_FEED
               ||'IDENTIFIED BY '||rcRemote.password_remote||kLINE_FEED
               ||'USING '||rcRemote.host_connection;
     --
     Begin
      execute immediate vSentence;
     Exception
      when others then
           p_oError:=sqlcode;
           p_oMessage:='Error creating db link:'||sqlerrm;
           raise ex_exit;
     end;
    --
    vSentence:=  'insert into '||rcRemote.schema_remote||','||rcRemote.table_remote||'@'||vLink_name||kLINE_FEED
               ||'select *'||kLINE_FEED
               ||'from '||rcRemote.table_local||' a'||kLINE_FEED
               ||'where '||rcRemote.condition;
     Begin
      execute immediate vSentence;
     Exception
      when others then
           p_oError:=sqlcode;
           p_oMessage:='Error inserting:'||sqlerrm;
           raise ex_exit;
     end;
    --
    vSentence:=  'drop DATABASE LINK '||vLink_name;
     --
     Begin
      execute immediate vSentence;
     Exception
      when others then
           p_oError:=sqlcode;
           p_oMessage:='Error dropping db link:'||sqlerrm;
           raise ex_exit;
     end;
  Exception
    when ex_exit then
         null;
    when others then
         p_oError:=sqlcode;
         p_oMessage:=sqlerrm;
  End pr_copy;
  --
End pk_remote;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have written the code and it working absolutely fine. Thank you so much Alvalongo.